# Fabric.js makes jQuery script fail on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I use Fabric.js to make a product customizer.

To get an interface with other interactions, I use *jQuery*. On *Firefox* everything works fine, but on *Chrome*, the *jQuery* part fails. No error is displayed.

I use other javascript scripts on this same page (*Tinymce*, *jQuery Form Plugin*). But I made a first debug and if I do **not load** *Fabricjs* on the page, the *jQuery* part executes **well**.

You will see other plugins loaded, it's from the CMS we use.

The *jQuery** part is the one I have problems with. It is the one handling the three tabs on the right part of the page (on click content under them should change).

---

I try to make a *JSFiddle* but the problem doesn't appear, so here is the page : 
[page](http://minu.me/cgaf)

You can login with:

Name:     demo

Password: demo

---

Thank you :)

---

**EDIT :** I have found a way to avoid the problem : I comment the "*"Click" event proxy*" in Fabric.js file. This redefinition seems to be in conflict with jQuery.

Comment: So, where do you place `script` tags? in the `head` or at the end of the body?

Comment: @djay In the `head` of the page. Do you think that could be a problem ?

Comment: Yes, this could be a problem since some browsers treat priority of script loading in different way. Try putting your `script` tags at end of your `body` tag. This should be inside `<body>` but it should be last thing inside that